# Stop function from being called on Render EVERY TIME

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React.JS app I have a function inside of a Functional Component that renders JSX that I need when the app loads initially. The catch is I don't need it re-run every time the component updates and the `return()` method is called. This content is rendered with an API call and it's "expensive" to re-run constantly.

How do I limit how often this will run.

```
...

<Col lg="8">
    <div className="tab-content" id="newForm-wrapper">
        {/* !! STOP THIS FROM BEING CALLED EVERY RENDER !!! */}
        {renderSectionContent(formJSON)}
    </div>
</Col>

...
```

Below is the function being called:

```
const renderSectionContent = json => {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty("form") && json.form.hasOwnProperty("sections")) {
        return json.form.sections.map((section, i) => {
            return <FormSection key={i} json={section} />;
        });
    } else {
        return <FormSection json={{}}/>;
    }
};
```

Comment: If you’re using a recent version of React check out React.memo. Otherwise you can use a class property to memoize it yourself so it’s only called once. Also, using index for react keys is an anti-pattern. Try using something content-based if possible like a unique id or textual content.

Comment: Is the body of `renderSectionContent` complete in the code provided? Doesn't look like it's making any API call or is "expensive".

Comment: Will you be wanting to re-run the function if the json data changes? or are you not expecting it to change?

Comment: @Christopher I'll try Memo. Thanks for the tip on the index as well! 

@MaazSyedAdeeb `<FormSection />`is rendering with an API call. You don't see that.

@DevinCenatiempo I would like to trigger the change on a specific event, such as an updated JSON.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent this function from being run every render, you will need to store return value of the function in local state. You will probably want the function to be re-run every time the json data changes, which can be difficult if the json has deeply nested data. Depending on how you are injecting the json into your component will change exactly how you will set the state.

Here is an example of how this would be done assuming the data was passed as a prop to your class component:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sectionContent: renderSectionContent(props.formJson),
    };
  }

  renderSectionContent = json => {
    // do stuff
    return <FormSection />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Col lg="8">
        <div className="tab-content" id="newForm-wrapper">
          {sectionContent}
        </div>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}
```

Or using Hooks (new starting in React version 16.8):

```
export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const [sectionContent, setSectionContent] = useState(renderSectionContent(props.formJson));

  const renderSectionContent = json => {
    // do stuff
    return <FormSection />;
  }

  return (
    <Col lg="8">
      <div className="tab-content" id="newForm-wrapper">
        {sectionContent}
      </div>
    </Col>
  );
}
```

Comment: Very cool idea, I will try and explore this in the next day or so.

Comment: In the functional component, the second example, shouldn't be this.state.sectionContent, but only sectionContent

Comment: yes, sorry, I'll make that edit. It happens when you don't have an IDE to bark at you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your json input to your function is either being passed down as a prop to your component or is in state ( if it's not maybe you could store it in state? ) :

Two of some of the options you could use here are to either make that function into it's own component with returns the desired component based on the condition; this way you can pass down json as a prop and it will only run again if that prop changes. Or you could use `createSelector` from the [react reselect library](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) where you hold your json in state (or you can replace state with props in the example below ) and you pass in your state or prop to your function (which will now be a reselect function).  This way your function will only run again if your json in state or props changes

Example

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

static renderSectionContent = createSelector(
    (state) => state.json,
    (json) => {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty("form") && 
            json.form.hasOwnProperty("sections")) {
                return json.form.sections.map((section, i) => {
                    return <FormSection key={i} json={section} />;
                });
        } else {
            return <FormSection json={{}}/>;
        }
    }
)


render() {
    let selectionContent = this.renderSectionContent(this.state)


    ..

    <Col lg="8">
        <div className="tab-content" id="newForm-wrapper">
            {selectionContent}
        </div>
    </Col>

   ...
}
```

every time createSelector is called, it will return the previous computed return from the function, unless one of the inputs to the createSelector function change

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change

```
...

<Col lg="8">
    <div className="tab-content" id="newForm-wrapper">
        {/* !! STOP THIS FROM BEING CALLED EVERY RENDER !!! */}
        {renderSectionContent(formJSON)}
    </div>
</Col>

...
```

To

```
...

<Col lg="8">
    <div className="tab-content" id="newForm-wrapper">
        {/* !! STOP THIS FROM BEING CALLED EVERY RENDER !!! */}
        {() => renderSectionContent(formJSON)}
    </div>
</Col>

...
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

> Use an [IIFE](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression-a0ed32b66c18) to cache your JSX.

The best solution is to use a Class component instead of Functional, in this case. But still, if you are reluctant to use those for whatever reasons, an IIFE is one of the resorts you have. How to do that? Check the below code.

```
import React from 'react'
...
...

export default (function () {
  let cachedJSONString = ''
  let cachedSectionContent = null

  const renderCachedSectionContent = json => {
    let newJSONstring = JSON.stringify(json)

    if (cachedJSONString) {
      if (cachedJSONString !== newJSONstring) {
         cachedJSONString = newJSONstring
         return renderSectionContent(json)
      } else {
         return cachedSectionContent
      }
    }

    cachedJSONString = newJSONstring
    cachedSectionContent = renderSectionContent(json)

    return cachedSectionContent
  }

  const renderSectionContent = json => {
   if (json.hasOwnProperty("form") && json.form.hasOwnProperty("sections")) {
       return json.form.sections.map((section, i) => {
         return <FormSection key={i} json={section} />;
       })
    } else {
       return <FormSection json={{}}/>;
    }
  }

  return (props) => {
    return (
      ...
       <Col lg="8">
          <div className="tab-content" id="newForm-wrapper">
             {renderCachedSectionContent(props.formJSON)}
          </div>
       </Col>
      ...
    )
  }
})();
```

**Q. But, why IIFE?**

**A.** To [avoid cluttering global Namespace](https://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#namespace).